# Joining vertical and horizontal table

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

How can I do a join that takes the two tables and get the table in result. Having trouble thinking about it because one is a horizontal table and the other is a vertical table I believe. The other answers on SO are not clear to me because I have to join a value in a row with a column name. How can I do that?

```
CREATE TABLE forecast (
   year integer,
   week integer,
   model varchar(50),
   category varchar(50),
   subcategory varchar(50)
);  
insert into forecast (year, week, model, category, subcategory) values (2021, 1, 'AAA', 'CategoryA', 'SubcategoryA');
insert into forecast (year, week, model, category, subcategory) values (2021, 1, 'BBB', 'CategoryA', 'SubcategoryA');
insert into forecast (year, week, model, category, subcategory) values (2021, 1, 'CCC', 'CategoryB', 'SubcategoryB');
insert into forecast (year, week, model, category, subcategory) values (2021, 1, 'DDD', 'CategoryA', 'SubcategoryC');

CREATE TABLE translation (
    type varchar(50),
    name varchar(50),
    translated varchar(50)
); 
insert into translation (type, name, translated) values ('category', 'CategoryA', 'TranslatedCategoryA');
insert into translation (type, name, translated) values ('category', 'CategoryB', 'TranslatedCategoryB');
insert into translation (type, name, translated) values ('subcategory', 'SubcategoryA', 'TranslatedSubcategoryA');
insert into translation (type, name, translated) values ('subcategory', 'SubcategoryB', 'TranslatedSubcategoryB');
insert into translation (type, name, translated) values ('subcategory', 'SubcategoryC', 'TranslatedSubcategoryC');



CREATE TABLE result (
    year integer,
    week integer,
    model varchar(50),
    category varchar(50),
    subcategory varchar(50)
); 


insert into result (year, week, model, category, subcategory) values (2021, 1, 'AAA', 'TranslatedCategoryA', 'TranslatedSubcategoryA');
insert into result (year, week, model, category, subcategory) values (2021, 1, 'BBB', 'TranslatedCategoryA', 'TranslatedSubcategoryA');
insert into result (year, week, model, category, subcategory) values (2021, 1, 'CCC', 'TranslatedCategoryB', 'TranslatedSubcategoryB');
insert into result (year, week, model, category, subcategory) values (2021, 1, 'DDD', 'TranslatedCategoryA', 'TranslatedSubcategoryC');
```

This

```
select * from forecast f
left join translation t
on t.name = f.category or t.name = f.subcategory
```

translates one at a time which makes sense, but I can't get two columns out of it that translate each column

Answer (score 3):

Double left join on the type and the name.
And a coalesce to default to the original name if there's no translation.

> ```
> select f.year, f.week, f.model
> , coalesce(cat.translated, f.category) as category 
> , coalesce(subcat.translated, f.subcategory) as subcategory
> from forecast f
> left join translation cat 
>   on cat.name = f.category 
>  and cat.type = 'category' 
> left join translation subcat 
>   on subcat.name = f.subcategory
>  and subcat.type = 'subcategory'
> order by f.year, f.week, f.model;
> ```

| year | week | model | category | subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | AAA | TranslatedCategoryA | TranslatedSubcategoryA |
| 2021 | 1 | BBB | TranslatedCategoryA | TranslatedSubcategoryA |
| 2021 | 1 | CCC | TranslatedCategoryB | TranslatedSubcategoryB |
| 2021 | 1 | DDD | TranslatedCategoryA | TranslatedSubcategoryC |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=929c9ee6ae79eaa0669c6870c6a2f182)*

Answer (score 0):

We have to do a multiple join. One for each column.

```
select f.year, f.week, f.model, t.translated as 'category', t2.translated as 'subcategory' 
from forecast f
left join translation t
on t.name = f.category 
left join translation t2
on t2.name = f.subcategory
```

Comment: Aside: A good habit, and one to encourage, is to assign table aliases that are at least faintly meaningful. `t` and `t2` don't communicate much. Even `tc` and `tsc` would be an improvement.